# Onsen UI popPage() issue

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

Currently I'm developing a phonegap application using onsen ui and angularJS. I'm trying to pop a page using

```
<ons-back-button onclick="myNavigator.popPage()">Back</ons-back-button>
```

I've used same code for "Back" button on every page. But the problem is when I push multiple pages using

```
<ons-button modifier="large" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('in_menu.html', { animation : 'slide' } )" style="margin: 220px auto;">
      Next
</ons-button>
```

and when I use "Back" button, it Pops two pages instead of only one page. Some please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be unable to reproduce the issue only with the information provided unfortunately. Here's a working [Demo](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/MepZze?editors=1000).

Maybe you could provide a codepen, so that we can see it. Sorry if I'm not being of much use.

On a side-note - if you just have a backbutton in your page it should be able to have the same functionality by default. Maybe somehow in your case the default wasn't prevented but yours is also executed.

Another very important note here is the version of onsen since there were some changes regarding this behaviour.

If you're using the a recent version you could try to use `onClick` property instead (however you need to do it in javascript, not in the html).

I can update my answer if you provide some more info :)